# How do I disable the mouse pointer so that inadvertent click doesn't move typing cursor to an undesirable location?

Tags: java, mouseevent, keypress

--MAJOR EDIT from several days ago---

For each cell in a "Solitaire Scrabble" game, I have (a) `mouseListener`, (b) `mouseMotionListener`, and (c) `keyListener` in order to (a) allow clicking to reposition the text cursor, (b) allow dragging content from one `JTextField` to another or to highlight a string of cells for scoring, and (c) enable cursor keys to provide a way of moving around the grid. Each letter that is played has relevant info (row, column, letter, colors) stored onto a stack for undo-ing and redo-ing. Despite the complexity, it works almost perfectly.

But with the mouse pointer positioned (lower right in left grid) far from the text cursor, if I accidentally click BUTTON1 and then *immediately* type 'S', the 'S' winds up where it should on the board (middle grid), BUT it does NOT wind up in the stack--i.e., it can't be undone. YET IF I DON'T TYPE THE 'S' SO FAST, all is well (right grid). It's almost as if the key listeners get shut out by the quickness of typing after clicking.

[image]

**Is there a relationship among** `keyPressed`, `keyTyped`, `keyReleased`, and `mouseClicked` **that can explain this?** It is clearly a timing issue since the ONLY way to get the "bad" behavior in the middle grid above is to click-and-within-0.12 seconds-type-a-letter: *boomboom*, that quick.

Here's the essence of the most relevant methods. I don't expect much help with this. An SSCCE seems impossible to construct--it would NOT be short. I'm hoping a light bulb will go off in someone's brain after reading the description--"Hey, that happened to me!" Mine are all burned out.

Note that `push`ing of cells (both to `highlightedWordStack` and `undoStack`) is conditional, but it WORKS for ALL cases EXCEPT when click-type occurs quickly enough.

```
  private  void keyPressedAction(KeyEvent e){

      int key  = e.getKeyCode();
      int mods = e.getModifiers();

      if(    cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].getForeground()== F_NORMAL 
          && cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].getText().length() > 0
          && ! Highlighter.alreadyHighlighted(currentCell, highlightedWordStack))
      {
        highlightedWordStack.push
          (new HighightedCellRecord(
            cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].getText().charAt(0),
            currentCell.row,currentCell.col,
            cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].getForeground(), 
            cells[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].getBackground()));
      }

      setCursorAndCell(currentCell);
  }

  private  void keyTypedAction(KeyEvent e){

      int mods = e.getModifiersEx();    
      char ch  = e.getKeyChar();

      int r = currentCell.row;    
      int c = currentCell.col;

    if(Utilities.isUppercaseLetter(ch) && mods == 0 || ch == '*')
    {
    int w = Utilities.String__containsChar_At(txtUser, ch);      

    undoStack.push
                    (new PlayByPlayRecord(ch, w, cells[r][c].getForeground(), 
                            r, c, 0, rep, repIndex, 
                            txtUser[w].getForeground(), F_NORMAL, -1));
    }
  }

  private void keyReleasedAction(KeyEvent e){

    ctrlIsDown = false;
    shiftIsDown = false; 
   }


  private  void cellsMouseClickedAction(MouseEvent e){

    int xpix = e.getComponent().getLocation().x;
    int ypix = e.getComponent().getLocation().y;
    int r = Utilities.interp(ypix);
    int c = Utilities.interp(xpix);

    setCursorAndCell(new GridCell(r, c));
  }

  private  void setCursorAndCell(GridCell cell){

    int r = cell.row;
    int c = cell.col;
    cells[r][c].grabFocus();
    currentCell.col = c;
    currentCell.row = r;
    if(cells[r][c].getText().length() > 0)
      currentCell.content = cells[r][c].getText().charAt(0);
    else
      currentCell.content = 0;
  }
```

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses